# Stop vlc window from popping up

Tags: vlc-media-player

I am batch converting a lot of files and running vlc from the command line. When I do a new dos box pops up showing vlc's output converting the current file. It is very annoying because it pops up above all other windows and takes focus.

How do I hide VLC either completely or minimized.

Comment: It's very annoying when I'm trying to run a playlist on startup from the command line. And `--no-qt-error-dialogs` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

No need for Command User Interface (DOS) commands. 
The switch is within the app. 
Click on TOOLS MENU > PREFERENCES (or Ctrl+P). 
Under INTERFACE... 
Turn this off: 
"Systray pop-up when minimized" CHECKBOX. 
Systray will still notify you with a little balloon. 
But the video itself will no longer pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `--quiet` and `--dummy-quiet -I dummy` suppresses the popup window.

Answer (score 1):

Either minimise or run VLC using the command line with the **--qt-start-minimized** option.
(ex:`vlc.exe sourceUrlStreamOrFile.mp3 :sout=#file{dst="D:\\targetFile.mp3"} :sout-keep --run-time=65 --stop-time=65`**--qt-start-minimized**`vlc://quit`)

Then while running, turn off "tools/preference/interface/Systray pop-up" option to prevent any popup from the system tray icon.

Then to run your batch, use `cmd /c start /b yourbatch.bat`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `>nul` on the end of the vlc command.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Preferences > Interface >
For dropdown of:  Auto raising the interface, chose: Never. By default it is Video.